Indian Railways: Seat assignments for passengers split between confirmed and waitlist status
We purchased Indian Railways tickets for two passengers in the Chair Car Coach. One passenger was immediately placed in CNF (confirmed) status and got a seat number; the other was initially placed in WL1 (waitlist) status, but is now CNF as well. When we travel, will we get side by side seating?
